# How to get referrer code from playstore using Play Install Referrer Library?

Tags: android

I'm going to use [Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)

I have read many articles, but none of them tell you how to create a link

for example, I have the code "KSK23DG"
What should the link look like so that I can get it in my application?

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<apppid>...

val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
val referrerUrl: String = response.installReferrer
val referrerClickTime: Long = response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
val appInstallTime: Long = response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
val instantExperienceLaunched: Boolean = response.googlePlayInstantParam
```

Answer (score 9):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64928842/can-my-app-know-which-qr-code-was-used-to-download-it/64930215#64930215).

### Passing data to Google Play Store

You can pass in referrer data with the `referrer` URL query parameter:

One of your links could look like this (replace `com.example.myapp` with your real application ID):

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.myapp&referrer=someid%3Dsomedata`

This URL consists of the following parts:

- Base URL for the store page of an app on the Google Play Store:

  - `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=`
- Your application ID:

  - `com.example.myapp`
- `referrer` URL parameter:

  - `&referrer=`
- Your freely choosable key-value data. In this case with `someid` as a key and `somedata` as a value (note, that `%3D` is the HTML URL enconding for `=`):

  - `someid%3Dsomedata`

### Testing

In order to test this, you will need to upload your app to the Play Store into the internal, alpha, beta or production track. As far as I am aware, this does not work with [internal app sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/).

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that through this `referrer` is how they make Deferred Deep Links work as well?

Comment: @Starwave Yes this is how defered deep links work for android apps on the play store. After the app install you check with the Play Referrer Library if a referrer has been passed and react to it: https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library#install-referrer